# How to activate a specific Python environment as part of my submission to Slurm?

Tags: python, slurm, sbatch

I want to run a script on cluster (SBATCH file).

1. How can activate  my virtual environment (path/to/env_name/bin/activate).
2. Does I need only to add the following code to my_script.sh file?

   module load python/2.7.14
   source "/pathto/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/bin/activate"

Comment: Just run the `python` executable in the `bin` folder of the virtual environment.

Comment: can you be more precise please?

Comment: I think @KlausD. is suggesting you run something like `/path/to/miniconda3/envs/allennlp/bin/python -m allennlp.run --version`.

Comment: did you try using `#SBATCH --export=ALL`?

Comment: Would you mind posting a full example of the solution, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just make sure to insert those lines after the `SBATCH ...` lines and before any use of `python`.

Comment: what if my submission script **is** a python script? I can't just do that...

Comment: how do i create this environment on ALL nodes of my slurm cluster?

Comment: Which lines? Can you post a full example?

Answer (score 23):

You mean to activate a specific Python environment as part of your submission to Slurm? This is what I add to my job script and it works well. Note that I use Anaconda, which by default adds the required paths to my .bashrc script after installation. Hope this helps.

```
....
# define and create a unique scratch directory
SCRATCH_DIRECTORY=/global/work/${USER}/kelp/${SLURM_JOBID}
mkdir -p ${SCRATCH_DIRECTORY}
cd ${SCRATCH_DIRECTORY}

# Activate Anaconda work environment for OpenDrift
source /home/${USER}/.bashrc
source activate MyEnvironment 

# we execute the job and time it
time mpirun python slurmscript.py
```

Comment: what if my submission script is a python script?

Comment: You should be able to just execute your python script where I call mpirun. At that point the Anaconda environment is setup